# TFS 2013 Licensing

Tags: tfs, licensing

Hi we are a team of 15 developers and we all have VS 2013 professional(without MSDN Subscription) and we have one TFS Server License(Standard type).

I wanted to know do we need to procure a CAL License , because in my visual studio i already see a option of Team and we can connect to tfs without any problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after finally speaking with the microsoft executive. The guy told me that tfs does not stop you from connecting to it from your VS(since VS now have inbuilt option of team), but those connections are illegal and would be a problem if there is a audit.

Answer (score 4):

TFS permits working even without licenses: it is up to the TFS Administrator to match license with users and limit their access.

As a rule of thumb, you need a CAL for each users (note: the same user can access through multiple accounts) and an MSDN subscription include a TFS CAL, otherwise you need to buy them. There are cases and exceptions, so you should look for the definitive answer in the [Visual Studio 2015 and MSDN Licensing White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350).